# Replacement for pumpkin

Tags: substitutions, pumpkin

I have a recipe that requires pumpkin, but I would like not to use it.
Are there other vegetables, or combination of vegetables I could use? I would like to get the same consistency; if then the taste is similar, that is a bonus.

I report the list of ingredients used for the recipe:

- Tofu (250 gr)
- Onion (1)
- Pumpkin (200 gr)
- Parsley
- Pasta (400 gr)

The pumpkin is cut in cubes, cooked covered with few water for 15 minutes, and then the other ingredients are added. All is cooked for 10 minutes more.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The closest in terms of taste an texture would be another winter squash such as butternut, acorn, hubbard, etc. (As has already been mentioned.)

However, anything with a similar texture would work. If you don't care so much about the taste, you could substitute a tuber such as potato, turnip, rutabaga, carrot, parsnip, celery root, or parsley root.

Sweet potatoes or yams would be closer in taste, but might be mushier than you want.

I'd suggest experimenting with any single or combination of the above and see what flavor you like best.

Comment: I have substituted sweet potatoes for pumpkin pretty often and it has worked quite well.

Comment: I have eaten sweet potatoes in Long Island that had a taste very close to pumpkin; I have not found sweet potatoes in Italy with the same taste as those one, though.

Answer (score 7):

You might try butternut squash.

Comment: Any of the 'winter squash' will work -- acorn, butternut, hubbard, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have substituted carrots for sweet potatoes in pies. I cover the carrots with just enough water to cover them and boil until they are soft. I then blend them until they are mixed into a paste with the water they were bolied in, reserving 1/2 cup. Since carrots do not have the starch that pumpkin or sweet potatoes have, I combine 1 tablespoon of corn starch to the 1/2 carrot water and follow the rest of the recipe of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Sweet potatoes or butternut squash sound like the best options, but any hard winter squash or root vegetable would probably work fine.